# Getting success response but don't get notification NODE.JS

Tags: node.js, firebase, push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send fcm-node push notification to device. I get success but notification was not received. Here is my code:

```
const FCM = require('fcm-node');

let sendNotification = function(regToken) {
var serverKey = 'MY_SERVER_KEY';
var fcm = new FCM(serverKey);

var message = {
    to: regToken, 
    notification: {
        title: 'Title of push notification', 
        body: 'Body of push notification',

    priority: "high",
    time_to_live : 20
    }
};
fcm.send(message, function(err, response){
    if (err) {
        console.log("Something has gone wrong!", err);
    } else {
        console.log("Successfully sent with response: ", response);
    }
});
}
```

and I am getting:

```
Successfully sent with response:  {"multicast_id":8758415454661889533,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1543920988555705%03634db303634db3"}]}
```

Comment: Check with firebase console. Try sending the notification from there to the same token. The code here looks fine.

Comment: It would help determine the issue if you mentioned which client platform you're sending the message to.

Comment: Did you figure this out, I am having the same issue...